# Atualizar Label de uma Window através do Conteudo de uma ComboBox de um UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Eu tenho :

Uma Window:

- Window1 (MainWindow)

Três UserControls:

-UserControl1

-UserControl2

-UserControl3

Na janela 1 eu tenho uma label (label1) e em cada um dos UserControls tenho uma ComboBox.

Cada ComboBox tem 3 opções: AZUL, PRETO e BRANCO. As mesmas 3 opções para cada uma delas.

O objetivo é quando eu selecionar uma opção em um UserControl, a label da mainWindow atualiza. Se eu selecionar Preto no UserControl1, o conteúdo da Label mostra Preto.

Se, em seguida, eu vou para o USERCONTROL2 e selecionar branco, o conteúdo da label atualiza para branco (substitui basicamente).

Eu uso C# e WPF.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você deve criar o evento "SelectionChanged" para seu userControl, e quando o comboBox disparar esse evento, ele será repassado ao userControl.

Veja o exemplo de um userControl:

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
 {
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public event EventHandler ComboXSelectionChanged;
    private void comboWindow2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboXSelectionChanged != null)
            ComboXSelectionChanged(this, e);
    }

    public object SelectedComboValue
    {
        get { return comboWindow2.SelectedValue; }
        set { comboWindow2.SelectedValue = value; }
    }
 }
```

[image: UserControl]

Depois, no seu Window você deve capturar este evento e fazer o que precisa:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userControl1.ComboXSelectionChanged += userControl1_ComboXSelectionChanged;
    }

    void userControl1_ComboXSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelTexto.Content = userControl1.SelectedComboValue.ToString();
    }


}
```

Funcionando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito Obrigado :)